# Why this search button looks different in google chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this [SITE](http://goo.gl/mttyJN) there is a form at the home page. (Refresh the page again if you are unable to see the form during your first visit.)

the form look ok in fire fox.
Ive used customized it as far as I know bit of CSS.

But it does not look ok in Google chrome?

Also how can make those all fields width to 100% for smaller screen? I tried but search button is not going down.

I think I miss somthing related to `Position` and `display`..

This is the media query I am using

```
#search_btns_h { margin-left: 3% !important; padding: 4.5% 38.5% !important; }
.hotel-day-select { height: 42px; border-radius: 3px; width: 230px; }
@media only screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width: 1135px)  {
    .hotel-destination { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 9px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1380px) {
    #search_btns_h {
        margin-left: 21% !important;
        padding: 4.5% 29.5% !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1373px) {
    #search_btns_h {
        margin-left: 22% !important;
        padding: 4.5% 28.5% !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1317px) {
    #search_btns_h {
        margin-left: 23%;
        padding: 4.5% 27.5%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width: 1135px) {
    .hotel-date-times > li { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 9px; }
}
```

How can I adjust the CSS or other code to make the search button and other fields work cross browser compatibility and responsive?

**[EDIT]**

After clear the cache in G.hrome: http://tinypic.com/r/b4wcj8/9 and same page looks like this in FF: http://tinypic.com/r/2ldhqvq/9

Comment: Everything appears to be displaying correctly within Chrome for me. Can you possibly post a screenshot of what you're experiencing? And have you also attempted to clear to cache to ensure you aren't grabbing a cached version of the stylesheet within chrome?

Comment: @Jdsfighter After clear the cache in G.hrome: [http://tinypic.com/r/b4wcj8/9](http://tinypic.com/r/b4wcj8/9) and same page looks like this in FF: [http://tinypic.com/r/2ldhqvq/9](http://tinypic.com/r/2ldhqvq/9)

Answer (score 0):

U should set a width on your div `.search-button > div`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: that's not the proper answer.. anyhow that helped me... I've upvoted your answer.. thanks